# Markup within Foundation's grid system: Where to put a wrapper div?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm new to CSS-frameworks.

Normally I start my markup within the body by adding a div with the class "wrap". The purpose of that, is to get the content horizontally centered. And for having a top-, bottom-margin.

Now with Foundation I would like to keep that approach. But I'm not sure where to put the "wrap"-div.

That's what I got currently:

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      <div class="callout">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo with Foundation added on CodePen: http://codepen.io/mizech/pen/LWBOvQ

I mean: It works but I'm not sure if I do it right.

**Shall I keep it the way it is? Or should I put the "wrap"-div somewhere else?**

**Should I perhaps leave the "wrap"-div at all (when using Foundation) and doing something else instead?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a wrap div. Foundation has a maximum width set on the .row so anything inside it will conform to that grid. If you need you can add a class with vertical margins or padding to that row. If you need a full width row you just add the class .expanded to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) By the way: You've got a very cool homepage.

Comment: Thanks! Made with foundation btw.